# Remove old generated ListView-Entries

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a ListView-Control in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="conversationContent" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0,0,20" FontFamily="Global User Interface" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="conversationContentSource" IsSourceGrouped="False" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border x:Name="messageBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" CornerRadius="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding MTY, Converter={StaticResource messageAlignment}}" Child="{Binding MSG, Converter={StaticResource messageToRTF}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay" Source="{StaticResource conversationContentSource}"/>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
```

The `CollectionViewSource` is being set to some `ObservableCollection<Message>` at runtime from code behind.

Every Item in the `ObservableCollection` is being parsed by a Converter, it translates the complete Message (incl. BB-Codes) to a single `RichTextBlock`-Element, which contains other UI-Elements.

Sometimes, the CollectionViewSource.Source-Property changes to another `ObersableCollection<Message>`. When this happens, the ListView-Control builds up the new ItemList and displays it. As far as good.

The Problem is, the old Items are not going to be removed from Memory. Running the GC manually doesn't change anything here.

I tried to iterate through the old items and delete them before changing the Source.

```
for (int ix = conversationContent.Items.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Type: " + conversationContent.Items.ElementAt(ix));
    if (conversationContent.Items.ElementAt(ix) is RichTextBlock) {
        conversationContent.Items.RemoveAt(ix);
    }
}
```

But instead of RichTextBlock-Controls, there are only Objects of the type "Message". Why?

I need to say, some of the generated Elements can contain Canvas-Elements with an `update`-function, which is being called every 200ms by a timer-event. Can this event-Binding prevent the GC to kill this objects?

I need a way to free up the memory, when the controls are not longer in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should use a `RichTextBlock` as your `ItemTemplate`. Research attached behaviors or attached dependency properties to figure out how to add a property to the `RichTextBlock` that will convert your BB-code formatted message to `RichTextBlock` content. You can see an example that adds hyperlinked text to a `RichTextBlock` in WinRT XAML Toolkit [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f8ef5ce66b68#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/RichTextBlockExtensions.cs).

For investigating memory leaks check this question: [How to debug memory leaks in Windows Store apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730496/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-in-windows-store-apps)

Most frequent cause of memory leaks I see are event handlers that are never removed - make sure to remove all handlers on your `RichTextBlock`'s `Unloaded` event. Also check if disabling all of your animations (e.g. in your animated emoticons).

Comment: Thank you very much! The update-Listener of the smileys prevented the GC to kill them. - I'm going to take a deep breath of your mentioned depency properties.

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to use UI Virtualization -> http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2009/01/29/how-to-show-large-amounts-of-data-in-wpf-using-ui-virtualization/

That way, the ListView will recycle the controls used to render the data and will not use that much memory.

Comment: MSDN says: WPF provides the `ObservableCollection<T>` class, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that exposes the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. - I guest, you meant this?

Comment: Nope :) I meant, to prevent all those objects to be loaded in memory you could use the both UI and Data Virtualization. In Case of UI Virtualization the controls that are used to render the data bound to it will be recycled and so, less memory usage.

Comment: Whoa, behavior changed - wrong direction. I'm displaying a chat history. A lot of text lines, and one message containing 2000 animated Smileys. When I scroll down, the app converts the messages again - and creates new elements. The old ones aren't visible anymore, but they are still in memory. Edit: I don't want the entries to be removed when out of visible range, I want them to be destroyed when changing the ItemSource.

Comment: then basically what should suffice is if no reference to that collection of items exists in code. Make the list null so that it is released and the GC will take care of it.

Comment: Collection cleared and set to null - the generated RichTextBlock-Elements are still there...  Is there a way to find all existing RichTextBlock-Elements?

Comment: @max06 now i realized something. Why are the elements converted to a richtextbox item with a converter? Why not just override the ItemTemplate of the ListView and set it to a RichTextBox. That way the listview will generate richtextboxes for each indivitual item in it's ItemsSource and Virtualization, it will dispose them and release memory

Comment: Every Message can contain different BB-Code-Formattings and Images. There are 2 Ways to display them correctly: Translating to html + display in Webview-Element, or building up an RichTextBlock-Structure. The RTB-Element doesn't contain a "source"-property, nor binding possibilities. So I needed to construct it at runtime and attach the whole element to the parent object (Border). How can I manipulate the ItemTemplate to display the unique structure of a message?

Comment: maybe something like this may be usefull - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259021/mvvm-wpf-databinding-to-a-skype-like-chat

Comment: That's been my first attempt - but unfortunately there's no `RichTextBox`-Element in Windows Store Apps...